# ArangoDB error for List<int> type

Tags: arangodb

I am encountering an issue on a .Net object property with `List<Int>`. There is no problem to save the record but when retrieving it will throw an error message as seen below:

`{"The value \"1\" is not of type \"System.Int32\" and cannot be used in this generic collection.\r\nParameter name: value"}`

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Create an issue on github repo and post also structure of the class please.

Comment: Hi Yojimbo87, issue has been reported at https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET/issues/15 . thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For those who wants to get the latest patch by Yojimbo87, you may refer to https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET/issues/15